# How to run an AppleScript automatically once I insert a USB drive?

Tags: applescript

I need to rename and fill about 70 USB sticks. Having an Applescript run automatically when they are inserted would make it much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any external drive you connect to an OS X machine is mounted into `/Volumes`. If you watch that folder for changes, you can pick up on added external drives and process these. Running this code:

```
property ignoredVolumes : {"Macintosh HD", "Time Machine Backups"} -- add as needed
tell application "System Events"
    set rootVolume to disk item (POSIX file "/Volumes" as text)
    set allVolumes to name of every disk item of rootVolume
    repeat with aVolume in allVolumes
        if aVolume is not in ignoredVolumes then
            set name of disk item (path of rootVolume & aVolume) to newName
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

will rename drives that are not in your `ignoredVolumes` list (unplug all but those you want to ignore, run `ls /Volumes` in Terminal and add the names to the property) to `newName`. To have this triggered on every change, modify the codes to be a [Stay-Open script application](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW7):

```
property pollIntervall : 60 -- in seconds
property ignoredVolumes : {…} -- from above

on run
    my checkVolumes()
end run

on idle
    my checkVolumes()
    return pollInterval
end idle

on checkVolumes()
    tell … end tell -- from above
end checkVolumes
```

and save it in *AppleScript Editor* (select “AppleScript application”, make sure you tick “Stay Open” when you do). Once launched, the script will keep running, executing the `on idle` handler every `pollInterval` seconds.

This will do fine if you are basically doing a once-in-a-while batch job. If you want a more permanent solution that does not rely on running a stay-open script application, you can either

- attach a Folder Action Script to the `/Volumes` folder (hat tip to [Philip Regan on *Ask Different*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/8092/11948); details on how to configure the action in [this Mac OS X Hints post](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=154499&postcount=6)) – the advantage being you strictly process additions to `/Volumes`, or
- use `launchd` by creating a LaunchAgent with the `StartOnMount` key set to `true` – that will trigger the script / app the agent starts every time a filesystem is mounted (tip of the hat to [Daniel Beck at *Ask Different*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13723/11948); see [Apple’s Technical Note TN2083](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html) for the gory details).